# Duplicate class kotlin - Unity

Tags: unity3d, gradle, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor, facebooksdk

Есть ошибка при компиляции, внедряли **SDK Facebook Analitycs**, как я понимаю создались дубликаты похожий библиотек, проблема в том что я не понимаю как исключить дубликат, вот одна ошибка из 900 подобных:

```
Duplicate class kotlin.BuilderInference found in modules 
jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10) 
and 
jetified-org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar)
```

Предположил что есть конфликт между **org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10** и **org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50**

в custom **mainTemplate.gradle** проекта внедрил, не помогло:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.10'
}
```

Что ещё можете посоветовать?